# Why doesn't the redux state update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Everything Seems Fine to me, the Console logs work in the Action and in the Reducer but the Chrome Redux tools  show no action being  trigged and no state updates.

Here is my Component Class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { SimpleGrid,Box,Select,Input,InputGroup,InputRightAddon,Text,Heading ,Button,NumberInput,NumberInputField,} from "@chakra-ui/core";
import { Footer } from '../../layout/Main/components';
import {submitUserInput} from '../../utils/actions/userInput'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

 class UserInput extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            yieldStress:0,
            thickness:0,
            diameter:0,
            pMAX:0
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleSubmit=(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        this.props.submitUserInput(this.state);
    }

    handleChange=(event)=>{
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        const materialsList = this.props.materials.map((material)=>(
        <option value={material.yieldStress} key={material.id}>{material.name}</option>
        ));

    return (
        <Box>
        <Heading as="h4" size="md">Cylinder Details</Heading>
    <Text>{this.props.thickness}</Text>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
            <Select placeholder="Select Material of Cylinder" isRequired name="yieldStress" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    {materialsList}
            </Select>
            <SimpleGrid columns={2} spacing={8} padding="16px 0px">
                <Box>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <InputRightAddon children="(mm)"/>
                        <Input type="number" placeholder="Thickness of Cylinder"  roundedRight="0" isRequired name="thickness" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </InputGroup>
                </Box>
                <Box>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <InputRightAddon children="(mm)"/> 
                        <Input type="number" placeholder="Diameter of Cylinder" roundedRight="0" isRequired name="diameter"onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </InputGroup>
                </Box>
            </SimpleGrid>
            <SimpleGrid columns={2} spacing={8} padding="0px 0px">
                <Box>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <InputRightAddon children={<Text paddingTop="12px">(N/mm)<sup>2</sup></Text>} padding="0 4px"/>
                        
                        <NumberInput precision={2} step={0.2}  >
                            <NumberInputField  placeholder="Maximum pressure "  roundedRight="0" isRequired name="pMAX" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        </NumberInput>
                    </InputGroup>
                </Box>
                <Box>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <InputRightAddon children="(mm)"/> 
                        <Input type="number" placeholder="Factor of Saftey" roundedRight="0" isRequired name="FOS"onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </InputGroup>
                </Box>
            </SimpleGrid>
            <Box padding="8px 0" >
            <Button variantColor="teal" float="right" border="0"  type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </Box>
        </form>
        <Footer />
    </Box>
  
    )
}
 }

UserInput.protoTypes = {
    submitUserInput: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    thickness: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
 }
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    thickness: state.userInput.thickness
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
    submitUserInput: (userInput)=> dispatch(submitUserInput(userInput))
}}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserInput)
```

Here is My Action File

```
import { SUBMIT_REQUEST_SENT,SUBMIT_SUCCESS,SUBMIT_FAILURE} from '../types'
export const submitUserInput = ({yieldStress, FOS, diameter,pMAX,thickness }) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(submitRequestSent());
    try {
        console.log("Printing object in action")
        console.log({yieldStress, FOS, diameter,pMAX,thickness }) //This is Printed 
        dispatch({
            type: SUBMIT_SUCCESS,
            payload:{yieldStress, FOS, diameter,pMAX,thickness } 
        }
        );
    }
    catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: SUBMIT_FAILURE,
            payload: error.message
        })
        throw error;
    }

}

export const submitRequestSent = () =>
({
    type: SUBMIT_REQUEST_SENT,
})
```

And Here is the UserInput Reducer

```
import {
SUBMIT_REQUEST_SENT,SUBMIT_SUCCESS,SUBMIT_FAILURE
} from '../../actions/types'

const initialState = {
        userInput:{
            yieldStress:0,
            FOS:0,
            diameter:0,
            pMAX:0,
            thickness:0 
        }
    }

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SUBMIT_REQUEST_SENT:
            return {
                ...state,
            }
        case SUBMIT_SUCCESS:
            console.log("Submit has been sucessfull And below is the Payload"); //This is Printed
            console.log(action.payload)//This is Printed
            return {
                ...state,
                userInput:action.payload
            }
            
        case SUBMIT_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

And my root Reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import  authReducer from '../authReducer'
import userInputReducer from '../userInputReducer';

export default  combineReducers(
    {
        auth:authReducer,
        userInput:userInputReducer
    }
)
```

I will Appreciate any applicable solution/Explanation..thanks

Comment: Because you are not handling props changes in the component. To receive changes in the component you have to use componentWillReceiveProps(props) in Component Class component to handle props change. And then update the state.

Comment: @fahadali he did map `this.props.thickness` directly into in render, your comment isn't the issue

Comment: @isaac can you upload your code to sanbox? my best guess is cause `thickness` is nested inside `state` obj and `userInput` obj you might need to do some handling for the render somewhere

Comment: @HagaiHarari he should then dubug whether the props are updating in the render() or not. If its not updating use the componentWillReceiveProps(props) to check.

Comment: @HagaiHarari  I think it should at least have showed the updates in the Redux Dev tools and not in the Component if it was a Mapping problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your state you have a property called `userInput`, which is the state section controlled by `userInputReducer`.  That section has its own property which is also called `userInput` that stores the actual data.  It that what you intended?

If so, you need to map properties like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    thickness: state.userInput.userInput.thickness
})
```

If not, you need to rework your `userInputReducer` and `initialState` to remove the double nesting.

> Everything Seems Fine to me, the Console logs work in the Action and in the Reducer but the Chrome Redux tools show no action being trigged and no state updates.

This sounds to me like an issue with dispatching an asynchronous thunk action.  Redux cannot handle these types of actions without the appropriate middleware.  When you create the store, it should be something like this:

```
import reducer from "./reducer";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

I copy and posted your reducer code with a store set up as above.  I used a dummy component ( a button that increments `thickness` when clicked ) and I was not able to reproduce your issue.  That leads me to believe that the issue is in the configuration of the store itself.